# When used in a title, will "Development and present practice" be understood to mean past (historical) development or just the recent?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-request

My thesis deals with treatment of melanoma and it should explain the development and progress of various methods as well as the current practice. I spent a lot of time on trying to figure out a proper title, one that reflects both that I deal with past achievements but also the practice (then and now). I do not want to use the words "history" or "overview" because in my view it sounds more like mere a compilation of information.
When I use "the development and present practice", would it be understood that by "development" I mean something like "past achievements" or "history of progress"? I do not know whether the word "development" can be understood like that, going also in the past. I would like to express the following (in less words): *Treatment of melanoma: how research progressed in the past, what was the practice then and what it is now.*
Thanks a lot!

Comment: For your title, how about: "Treatment of Melanoma: Research Then and Research Now"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question no Development doesn't convey the meaning you hope it will.

> Deveopments and present practice

but that might make people think you are looking forward

> development of present Practice

Says you are going to discuss how we got to the present practice.